# Electron Javascript pass data from render to main and vice versa

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I guys, i'm stuck in this situation:

ive a render.js and main.js, in render.js a check if a variable is true or false, if is false send a message to main that open a showMessageBox that have a question, Yes or Cancel, if i click yes
I would like to that the main.js send to render a massage and the render.js, received this return message call a function contained in the render.js.

below is a piece of code that does not continue

render.js:

```js
let dayOpened = document.querySelector("#dayOpen").innerText;
if (dayOpened !== "False") {
            ipcRenderer.send("day-opened");
```

main.js

```js
ipcMain.on("day-opened", () => {
  dialog.showMessageBox(null, giornataApertaOptions, (response) => {

  }).then((arg) => {
    console.log(arg)
     if(arg.response === 1) {
     //send message to render if i click yes
    }
  })
})
```

Edit: I would to make sync the event sended from render and wait the click response to proceed..

how can I proceed?
Thanks!
Ric

Comment: Do you have an instance of the renderer in main.js? How are they connected to each other?

Comment: negative Sir, only:

`const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');` in render.js

and

`const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');`

`const { ipcMain } = require('electron')`

Comment: You can  use directly dialog in your renderer using const {
    dialog,  
} = require('electron').remote;
And then
dialog.showMessageBox(null, giornataApertaOptions, (response) => {
In your render

Comment: In fact, at the moment I used .remote as a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to emit an event in the element #dayOpen.

In the main it would be then:

```
document.querySelector("#dayOpen").dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myevent', parameters));
```

And in renderer you could listen to this:

```
document.querySelector("#dayOpen").addEventListener('myevent', function(e) {
  alert('Triggered');
});
```

Comment: therefore only JavaScript without the use of electron API ?